# using np.repeat multiple times to create a row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with only column names ( 45 columns) and no actual data.
I want to create a row within the dataframe so that 15 columns have data "A", 15 columns have data "B", and the last 15 columns have the data "C", like so in the example below.

```
1 2 3... 16 17 18...43 44 45
A A A... B  B  B... C  C  C
```

I didn't know how to do this using jupyter notebook so I'd created excel file and converted it to dataframe, but was there a way to do so using numpy or pandas in jupyter notebook?
I suppose you could use `np.repeat` in some kind of way but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `lists` to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['A']*15 + ['B']*15 + ['C']*15 
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  ... 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
0  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  B  B  B  B  B  B  ...  B  B  B  B  B  B  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C  C
```

Comment: if I wanted to make another index that has repeats of a set of data, for instance d,d,d,e,f go into columns 1 to 5, and another d,d,d,e,f go into columns 6 to 10, and so on, could I still use  a list to do this?

Comment: Yes. You can. Then you simply do `data=['d','d','d','e','f'] * 15`for repeating it 15 times.

Answer (score 1):

```
colnm = [str(i) for i in range(1, 46)]
data = np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], 15).reshape(1, -1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = colnm
```